# Website outputs strange character encoding

Tags: encoding, safari, character-encoding

I recently had someone contact me saying the [website](https://alaskaavalanche.org) they're trying to access is composed entirely of strange character encoding strings (see below).

[image: weird character display]

It displays fine in Chrome - it's only Safari that has the issue.  I've tested on multiple computers and numerous other people have accessed the site and no one else has reported being able to reproduce the issue.  Has anyone else seen this?  Suggestions?

Character encoding is set to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: looks like gzip

Comment: Thx.  Was at a loss of where to look.